# Does Numba Cuda Support any key-value data structures?

Tags: cuda, numba

Numba has a `typed_dict` implementation, but it seems to be for CPU-compiled code only. Does Numba.cuda support any key-value data structures (e.g. search trees)?

Comment: This kind of data-structure needs a GPU-specific implementation to be efficient on a GPU, because GPUs loose a lot of performance when memory access is not coalesced.

Comment: Not only this require a GPU-specific implementation, but it is generally much better to write a data structure specifically design for your given use-case. In many cases, you can mostly avoid the hash-map and replace it with an array. Moreover, using shared-memory is critical, but the amount of shared memory is pretty small so it should not be wasted. The best way to implement conflict handling is very dependent of the use-case. Because of that, even if Numba would provide such a data-structure (AFAIK it does not), it would be pretty inefficient compared to a specific (GPU) implementation.

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of September 2023, it does [not](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/cudapysupported.html#built-in-types).